# Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting Splitting out Sales

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell phone store.  I am wanting to separate out Airtime sales from Accessory sales.  Airtime sales have a PIN, Accessory sales do not.  Is there a formula that will separate out these sales for me? (Man I wish this was on SQL not spreadsheets..)

Here's the example in a google sheet (I'm willing to move it to Excel if needed though)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kia4ZmzVsT2gZTRnXhdHlBTqh-5ugLhNTpZHNV_RSE8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah there are a ton of easy formulas to do this but can you please specify, what you want the final result to look  like and where you want the values? like do you want an extra column that says airtime or accessory or?

Comment: Excel and Google sheets are not identical. Please tag only with the one you use. Especially when it comes to concepts like CF, etc, there are significant differences.

Answer (score 0):

I Added into your sample sheet an example formula in `column I`, it is an `arrayformula` so it will automatically populate the rows whenever you add data in them.

It is currently first checking if there is any value in `column B`, since it looks like that is always filled, then it checks if there is a pin, if yes, `airtime` if no `accessory`

Here is the formula:

```
=arrayformula(IF(len(B2:B)>0, IF(LEN(D2:D)>0,"Airtime","Accessory"),))
```

[image]